# Finding tangent lines parallel to other functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials, tangent-line

> Is there a value $x_0$ ∈ $\Bbb{R}$ such that the tangent to the graph of *(x) = sinh(x)* at $x_0$ is parallel to the line *y = 2x−2*? What about a tangent parallel to the line y = $\dfrac{1}{2}$x + 3?  Draw a qualitative sketch showing all the solutions you find.

I know that *sinh(x) =* $\dfrac{1}{2}(e^x − e^{-x})$ and that the derivative of *sinh(x) =* $\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + e^x)$.  The slopes of *y = 2x−2* and y = $\dfrac{1}{2}$x + 3 are 2 and $\dfrac{1}{2}$, respectively.  I then make $\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + e^x)$ = 2, $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in order to find a value that allows for the tangent of *(x)* to be parallel to the aforementioned functions.  However, I am not sure how to compute $\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + e^x) = 2$, $\dfrac{1}{2}$ to get the necessary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how to solve $\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + e^x) = 2$  to get the necessary values.

Let $y=e^x$.  Then you want to solve $y+\dfrac1y=4$.

Multiply through by $y\ne0$, and it's a quadratic equation:

$y^2+1=4y$, or $y^2-4y+1=0$.

Now solve the quadratic equation for $y$ and take $x=\ln y$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly.  Do you mind clarifying or expanding, please?

Comment: Note that $e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^{x}}$. Then, to solve your equation you substitute for $e^{x}$ to obtain an easily solvable quadratic. After that, you use logarithms to find $x$.

Comment: I agree with @JoshuaWang, and I expanded my answer; let me know if I should expand further

Comment: I got it.  My apologies.  I was just being a bit daft with what you meant by multiply through by y ≠ 0.  Thank you very much for your explanations!